# Obtaining a DateTime field from a JSON file

Tags: c#, json, datetime

This is a section of my JSON string file.

```
{
  "Abbrev": "ALEX",
  "MeetingDate": "\/Date(1679058000000+1100)\/",
```

This is the class creation

```
public class PFGetForm
    {
        public string Abbrev { get; set; }        
        public DateTime MeetingDate { get; set; }
```

I am trying to add the Meeting Date to a list

```
line.Add($"{form.MeetingDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")}");
```

The error message is:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime. Path: $.MeetingDate | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 61.'

FormatException: The JSON value is not in a supported DateTime format.
```

Trying to parse the MeetingDate field from the JSON file and add it to a list so I can then send it all to a csv file.

Comment: This is due to the default date format being ISO-8601 format and the format you passed in is not this format. You can write a custom date format perser for JsonSerializer though - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support?pivots=dotnet-7-0#custom-support-for--and-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your property as string:

```
public class PFGetForm
    {
        public string Abbrev { get; set; }        
        public string MeetingDate { get; set; }   
}
```

and then convert it to timestamp. Demo:

```
    string MeetingDate  = "1679058000000";
    DateTime timestamp = DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt64(MeetingDate));
```

Fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/puJYxm

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommed you to use Newtonsoft.Json. Otherwise you will not have any time for programming, since you will be very busy creating  custom converters for Text.Json .

```
 PFGetForm form = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PFGetForm>(json);

string date = form.MeetingDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy"); // "17-03-23"
```